# How to find the decision boundary for two set of data for knn classifier

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, k-means

I have two sets,

```
N1 = 10; N2 = 15; % Class sizes
set1=[0.333; 0.509; 0.607; 1.172; 0.275; 0.762; 0.850; 0.920; 0.556; -0.046];
set2=[ 0.295; -0.203; -0.097; 0.633; 0.147; 0.356; 0.235; -0.054; -0.024; 0.377; -0.180; 0.512; 0.428; -0.129; 0.094];
```

I want to find the decision boundary and decision regions for the (3,1)nearest neighbhor classifier. Any ideas, How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For simply visualizing the decision boundary and decision regions, it is often satisfactory to brute-force test your whole domain of interest.

Specifically, you'd define a set of discrete points that span your domain of interest, you'd step through each point evaluating to which class the point belongs, then you'd plot the results.

Maybe something like this:

```
%define your domain of interest
dx = 0.001;           
x = [-1.0:dx:2.0];

%step through each point and decide which class it is part of
x_class = NaN*ones(size(x));
for I=1:length(x)
    %apply your KNN decision algorithm here
    %it outputs a 1 for class 1, or it outputs a 2 for class 2
    x_class(I) = my_KNN_algorithm(set1,set2,rules,x(I));
end

%plot results
plot(x,x_class);
hold on;
plot(set1,ones(size(set1)),'ro');
plot(set2,2*ones(size(set2)),'gs');
xlabel('Value');
ylabel('Class');
legend('Test Point','Given Set 1','Given Set 2')
```